# Not disposing MemoryStream has side affects when disposing the StreamReader that uses it?

Tags: c#, idisposable, memorystream

Given the following code snippet:

```
try
{
    var myTxt = "";
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(myObject.GetType());
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()

    serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, myObject);
    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
    {
        myTxt = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
catch (IOException ioEx)
{
     //log or whatever...        
     throw;
}
```

Typically I'd have a using statement around my memory stream, 
but from my understanding disposing the StreamReader will close the Memory Stream.

So the question is, is there anything REALLY wrong with the above?

Comment: If `WriteObject` throws for any reason before the StreamReader gets a chance to wrap it, the MemoryStream will not get disposed.

Comment: @vcsjones so what would be the implications of not disposing it? Is there actually anything to clean up and the GC will simply clean up for us (eventually)?

Comment: You will be at the mercy of the GC to clean it up, so the MemoryStream will occupy memory for longer than it really needs it. That can lead to perf problems, like GC needing to happen more often because of increased memory pressure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its fine because `MemoryStream` doesn't hold unmanaged resources anyway, but if you wanted to be extra safe you could do this:

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream()
StreamReader reader = null;
try{
    serializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, myObject);

    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    reader = new StreamReader(memoryStream)
    //...
}
finally
{
    if(reader != null)
        reader.Dispose();
    else
        memoryStream.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could simplify your code as I don't see the point of writing, rewinding and reading:

```
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(facets.GetType());
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    serializer.WriteObject(stream, facets);
    string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to use either

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(...))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    myTxt = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Here both stream and reader will be disposed by runtime

or `Close()` manually both reader(writer) and stream

Comment: the reason he is not doing that is because StreamReader is disposing the underlying stream and when Dispose is called on stream afterwards it will throw an `ObjectDisposedException`.

Comment: @Yaur Calling Dispose a second time will have no side-affects. This code was flagged by a colleague and although I think it's best practice to dispose of the MemoryStream I'm not so sure its such a huge issue if i dont.

Answer (score 1):

To test your scenario, I've added

```
memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

to the end and received an `System.ObjectDisposedException`, your code seems valid.

Of course `vcsjones`'s comment is also valid.